# Looking for a pliers-like tool for making crushed tomatoes

Tags: equipment, tomatoes

I need a tool for crushing or mashing fresh tomatoes. I know I can use a grater but that takes too much table space for me to use and it's not comfortable enough - if you want to crush a tomato after you start eating, you need space for another plate to grate the tomato on top of it. You also have to stand up.

I am looking for a tool similar with an egg slicer, where you can simply push one side on top of the other to crush the tomato. Or like a nut cracker, so I can crush the tomato while holding it on top of my plate. And I can sit down when doing it.

Is there any instrument like that?

Comment: What kind of result are you aiming for? And what kind of tomatoes? Fresh? Skinned? Cooked?

Comment: A ricer with a plate w/ large holes?

Comment: Could you also clarify what your restrictions are? I'm having a little trouble understanding how a grater is too much table space, when it's smaller than the plate/bowl you'd be putting the tomatoes into anyways, so I'm not really sure what other kinds of tool recommendations might be too large as well.

Comment: I go with the ricer. A good quality one.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that it's for fresh tomatoes. Yes, ricer is probably exactly what I'm looking for - I have to try one. As for the space, to use the grater after you start eating, you need extra space for another plate. with the ricer, you can do it above your plate, without even having to stand up. I'll make the question more clear

Comment: Just stand well back!

Comment: @Strawberry - I'll put you in my ricer, to add some sweet flavor to my food. Sorry, I couldn't resist :)

Comment: I'm crushed. :-(

Comment: I don't think there is any good way to crush raw tomatoes over the plate during serving. There is always a chance of splattering your guests.

Comment: Nobody enters my house without a deflector shield :)

Comment: What dish are you crushing raw tomato over at service? Sounds like my kind of meal but I’ve never heard of the practice.

Comment: Why not a lemon squeezer?

Answer (score 2):

I think a lemon squeezer might work:

[image: lemon squeezer]

You would want to buy one in person so you can see the size of the holes, which vary a lot. I think some of the tomato would come out through the holes and some would be left behind mushed up in the squeezer, which you could shake out onto the plate.

Comment: Because there are so few holes in a lemon squeezer I think there's a big chance the tomato will just overflow through the top and splatter around. It works with lemons because the fruit itself doesn't fall apart and you can efficiently squeeze all the liquid out of it.

Comment: I'd enlarge the holes with a drill, having chosen one with plenty of holes to start with

Answer (score 1):

You could also try a food mill. They are a little bigger then a ricer but if you use a larger plate in it you'll get slightly bigger chunks of tomato.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to do this while seated makes most tools unsuitable.

If you're only going to be using relatively small tomatoes (heirloom plum tomatoes), I would use a nut chopper.  Not the grinder style, but the 'slap chop' style.